# setSectionResizeMode only resizes for what is currently shown

Tags: c++, qt

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Video: http://youtu.be/KBpf9oLxOq4

How can I resize it for all strings?

Edit: `ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnToContents(0);`

Comment: Bliep Bliep (video). Also how about recalling this function when refilling the list?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman: Hmm?